# Multiple channel and multiple sound card

Tags: python, audio

I need to do the following (if possible in Python):

1. output at the same time on multiple USB sound card (cheap one you
   can find on Amazon)
2. on the main audio file, I need to output temporary sound
3. if possible I would like also to be able to use on a given sound
   card only the left channel or the right channel for 2 differents
   main audio file.

I did try Pygame.mixer:
I managed to do 3) and 2) quite easily on the main audio output of the Pi but I did not manage to select different sound card neither to use multiple sound card.
- ( 
 Then I try sounddevice library with the following exemple: http://www.esologic.com/multi-audio/

I can play .wav files on multiple USB audio output (task 1) but I do not get how to do task 2 & 3.